# Can I make instances of an NSManagedObject in no particular NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm building an app which receives a number of listings from a web API, and allows the user to save some for offline viewing.  My usual approach would be:

1. Get the data from the API, and make a new Listing object for each datum
2. Save the object to the DB if the user chooses to do so.

But this is a Core Data app, so the context is what gets saved, not the object.  Under those circumstances, the above would become something like this:

1. Get the data from the API, and make an unmanaged Listing object for each datum
2. Move the object into the managed context if the user chooses to do so, then save the context

One approach to having an unmanaged and a managed version of Listing objects would be to have two classes, e.g. ManagedListing and UnmanagedListing - but that's a horribly repetitive way of doing it.

What I'd like is to make Listing a subclass of NSManagedObject; initialise a bunch of them without an NSManagedObjectContext; then when I want to save one, I either set its context or I copy its attributes to a new Listing inside a context.

Can I make instances of an NSManagedObject in no particular NSManagedObjectContext?  If so, how?

Comment: Why don't you make them all in a context and then delete them if you don't need them. Alternatively you can make them all separate objects and then just save them by transfering the information from each object to a ManagedObject obj.

Comment: If create-and-delete is the pattern for transient objects, is there a way to undelete them?  I don't like the two-classes solution as it would add work maintaining the relationship between them.

Comment: you have `[context deleteObject:]` and `[context insertObject:]` which will let you make changes between whether your object is "inserted" into the managed object context or not. When you want to save the current layout just call `[context save:]`

Comment: and I can call `[context insertObject:]` after I called `[context deleteObject:]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use two persistent stores, one in memory and one on disk. If the user wants to save, move the object to the other store using `assignObject:toPersistentStore:`.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS < 5.0 - **yes**.
In iOS >= 5.0 - **no**.

Comment: could you go into more detail?

Comment: If you will just alloc+init NSManagedObject: In iOS with version lower then 5.0 compiler will give a warning. In iOS with version higher or equal to 5.0 compiler will give an error.