# How to create standalone instance of Core Data NSManagedObject - not managed

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

How to create **standalone** instance of Core Data `NSManagedObject` - understand **not managed**

i have class

```
class Location: NSManagedObject {
....
}

let managedLocation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
   "Location", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext
) as Location

let standaloneLocation = Location() // didn't work
```

last expression throws exception

> CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on
>   NSManagedObject class '*AppName.Location*'

I understand Why - but is there a way to create temporary instance, which will not be saved ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make instances of an NSManagedObject in no particular NSManagedObjectContext?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244230/can-i-make-instances-of-an-nsmanagedobject-in-no-particular-nsmanagedobjectconte)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `nil` as the managed object context:

```
let standaloneLocation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
   "Location", inManagedObjectContext: nil
) as Location
```

Note that this creates an instance for you that is not inserted into the context; you still would not write code like:

`let standaloneLocation = Location()`

Comment: This can result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do what you are asking for is to create a new child context for this object.

- Create a new child context with an appropriate `NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType`
- Set the parent context of the child.
- Create your new managed object instance with the child context:

  let managedLocation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
     "Location", inManagedObjectContext: childContext
  ) as Location
- Do whatever you want to do with that object. If you do not want to merge it into the parent context, just dispose of the child context.

[Managed object contexts are intended to be "scratchpads"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html). The represent transactions or change sets, and are lightweight. If the changes that have been made to a context or the managed objects it owns are not needed, discard them.

It's important to remember that managed objects have a very close relationship with a managed object context - it's the context that provides most of the functionality. Because of this it's important to always create managed object instances *with* a valid context - even if it's a temporary one.